# Clock synchronization with ntp

Tags: azure, clock, azure-sql-database

I am implementing an IoT solution using Azure SQL Database as data store. The Android device synchronizes time with NTP.

I am reviewing the delay of data transmission and have noticed that the timestamp getutcdate() on Azure SQL Database is about 5 seconds ahead. Is there any way to synchronize clock for the Azure SQL to get a more accurate time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find very hard to believe that a service like azure would have the wrong time... off by as much as a 1 second... imagine 5... I find it very much more likely that the android device is wrong.

But, answering your question directly, no, theres is nothing you can do in the SQL Database to change it's time because it is a multi-tenant service...

If you did confirm the shift, notify azure via ticket! this is a critical error and should be correct immediately! Several contract items are bound in "second"s time-frames

**Edit 1**
I just tested my iPhone, macbook and pc. All clocks match with azure Database time... to the second!

Answer (score 1):

Clock drift is a common problem on systems, rely on the time on a single source to help determine the reference time. VMS at one point on Azure were sync'd once a week if I recall with a time service, not sure on the Azure SQL side - would assume something similar (looking for docs now on that). Considering the possible shared usage of a SQL server I wouldn't expect to be able to change that. Rely on the record order and database time as your 'master' time. Even if the sync is once per day, there's still the potential of drift between systems. You are also limited on some time services how often you can sync - so some degree of drift again is also to be expected, consider that in your application.